# Intel Graphics Driver for Mint Linux

Tags: graphics

Though Mint 14 is based on Ubuntu 12.10 I get the following error when running the Intel Driver Manager under Mint:

```
diagnostics-view.c/diagnostics_view_start: Running diagnostic Checking distribution...
main-window.c/on_diagnostics_finished: Diagnostics finished with an error
```

Yes, I am using the correct 64 bit edition for my install

By the way, I am using a **VIZIO CT15-A5 15.6-Inch Thin + Light Ultrabook with the Intel HD 4000 graphics processor** and at present my System information says the following for display:

```
Display
Display
Resolution  1920x1080 pixels
Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
Version 1.13.0
Monitors
Monitor 0   1920x1080 pixels
Extensions
BIG-REQUESTS    
Composite   
DAMAGE  
DOUBLE-BUFFER   
DPMS    
DRI2    
GLX 
Generic Event Extension 
MIT-SCREEN-SAVER    
MIT-SHM 
RANDR   
RECORD  
RENDER  
SECURITY    
SGI-GLX 
SHAPE   
SYNC    
X-Resource  
XC-MISC 
XFIXES  
XFree86-DGA 
XFree86-VidModeExtension    
XINERAMA    
XInputExtension 
XKEYBOARD   
XTEST   
XVideo  
XVideo-MotionCompensation
```

OpenGL

```
Vendor  Intel Open Source Technology Center
Renderer    Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile
Version 3.0 Mesa 9.0.3
Direct Rendering    Yes
```

Here is the output of inxi -Gx

```
funkdified@vizio ~ $ inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           X.Org: 1.13.0 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.0.3 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

Comment: Hi can you please elaborate on that last point?  Where would I find it, and how?

Comment: Hi Don. See my edit. It seems I do have the driver installed. Surprises me though because of the great video playback in windows and poor playback in Mint. Hmmm. I wonder what else I could be doing differently.

Comment: I have been experiencing lots of playback problems with VLC. I don't know on what player you've tried, but try MPlayer2 if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is probably because the Intel Driver Manager is not checking whether it *can* install on your distribution, it is just checking whether the distribution is Fedora or Ubuntu. This is usually done with the command

```
`uname -v`
```

For example:

```
$ uname -v
#36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012
```

or
    $ uname -v 
    #1 SMP Debian 3.2.32-1

If the Intel Driver Manager searches for a specific string, for example

```
$ uname -v | grep 'Fedora\|Ubuntu'
```

this will return false on a machine running Mint even though Mint is based on Ubuntu.

---

These are the steps necessary to modify lsb-release as suggested by @don_crissti below (taken from [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=128120)):

> ```
> $ sudo cp /etc/lsb-release /etc/lsb-release.bak 
> $ sudo pico /etc/lsb-release
> ```
>
> Replace with (I'm not sure exactly which lines are being checked here
>   by intel-linux-graphics-installer, but definitely not the last one.)
>
> > ```
> > DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
> > DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.10
> > DISTRIB_CODENAME=quantal
> > DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 14 Nadia"
> > ```
> >
> > $ sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer
>
> Follow installer and wait for it
>   to ask you to reboot. Once it is finished:
>
> > $ sudo rm /etc/lsb-release 
> >     $ sudo mv /etc/lsb-release.bak /etc/lsb-release

Comment: There is a workaround that I am after. I read about it once.. you can modify a file in the driver manager to allow the disto.. but I can't recall how.

Comment: @Abram - If you're sure your problems are caused by driver version and not by driver configuration... the checking is done via `lsb-release` in the source code so you'd have to modify it and re-compile the app. Instead of doing that you could modify `lsb-release` to trick the app. The workaround is described [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=128120). Make sure you read and understand the warnings.

Comment: Don, I will try your answer and Terdon's when I get hme tonight. I will first try the reconfigure, and then Terdon if I'm still experiencing issues. Thank you so much for your help Don.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I posted on AskUbuntu

There is a graphics gui by intel for download.

```
sudo apt-get install intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Then run the installer.

Your touchpad mouse may become unresponsive.
You can then do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This fixed the xserver crashes and the mouse wasn't disabled after every reboot.  If your mouse is disabled, do

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

But after re-downloading from the ppa, the issue resolved with the touchpad.